# Case Sensitivity Issue : MySQL and Autogenerated Tables in Spring Batch

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch along with Spring Boot in our application for creating Batch Job Processes. We are using MySQL as our database.

By default, Spring Batch generates all uppercase table names. An example being BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION. And all the jobs written worked well on our Windows system. But after we deployed the code on server where MYSQl point to Linux machine, running batch jobs resulted in the following error:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'dbmaster.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE' doesn't exist

This is because MYSQL database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and is case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.

Following properties were added into application.properties to generate the tables:

spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=ALWAYS

[Generated Spring Batch Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79Uia.png)

We tried changing this property to

spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
and tried creating the all the spring batch tables manually in lower case letters but it dint worked well as expected

We are looking for a solution for this case sensitivity issue that can be done in code part so that jobs will run fine in windows, mac or linux wherever deployed .

Comment: See [lower_case_table_names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) system variable. Adjust its value as you need.

Comment: Based on the error, the issue does not seem to be related to case-sensitivity. The table does not exist. Are you sure the tables are *correctly* created before running your job?